# How to access an bluetooth-agent with python script?

Tags: bluetooth, debian, pipe, agent, bluetoothctl

On a RPi4 with Debian I use

```
sudo bluetoothctl
  power on
  discoverable on
  pairable on
  agent NoInputNoOutput
  default-agent
```

to be able to pair e.g. my smartphone to this Rpi. These steps are also possible to trigger from an python script (e.g. with subprocess.run() ).

After that steps I can connect a profile like Audio streaming. In `bluetoothctl` it needs to

1. confirm the passkey with typing `yes` and press enter
2. confirm the "audio-request" in the agent with `yes` and press enter.

I would like to confirm the steps 1. and 2. with a python script. Like listening on the Bluetooth agent and as soon as it asks for confirmation, i would like to feedback `yes`.
But I don't know how I can interact with that Bluetoothctl agent on python.

I already tried to open a subprocess

```
returnstring = subprocess.run(["bluetoothctl"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, timeout = 5 )
```

in python with timeout (5s). My hope was, to finally get as STDOUT a string with the question about "... accepting profile: yes/no". But I just received an error and timeout.

Any proposals?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I automate pairing RPi and Android with bluetooth Batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66401660/how-can-i-automate-pairing-rpi-and-android-with-bluetooth-batch-script)

Comment: OK i understood that i need to use dbus to control bluetooth.
But the example code given in the post above did not help, as it is not working for me somehow... i need to check.