# Accepting bluetooth Pairing Requests in raspberrypi through python

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

I had a task to connect the Raspberry Pi Bluetooth and mobile device Bluetooth through Python code

1. I was able to connect the Raspberry Pi through SSH and make the raspberry pi bluetooth discoverable
2. when I send a pairing request from the mobile device to raspberry pi one popup dialog box appears to confirm the pairing, here i was unable to confirm pairing using python code
3. Manually we use "pair xx:XX:XX:XX:XX(device mac address)" command to confirm pairing
4. when i try to excute the  "pair xx:XX:XX:XX:XX(device mac address)" command through python, its not accepting the request

Any suggestions or ideas, how can i confirm pair request from mobile device using python script

Comment: There should be plenty of answers on here about such things. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66403748/7721752

Comment: @ukBaz i was unable to get, can you provide some other source

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking with your last comment please